# error in creating charge coinbase commerce through post request

Tags: javascript, http-post, coinbase-api

i am trying to create a charge in coinbase commerce

```
const query = {
    name: 'The Sovereign Individual',
    description: 'Mastering the Transition to the Information Age',
    local_price: {
        amount: '100.00',
        currency: 'USD',
    },
    pricing_type: 'fixed_price',
    metadata: {
        customer_id: 'id_1005',
        customer_name: 'Satoshi Nakamoto',
    },
    redirect_url: 'https://charge/completed/page',
    cancel_url: 'https://charge/canceled/page',
};
const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CC-Api-Key': '6225fe4d-f9a8-498f-8085-11dea4212316',
        'X-CC-Version': '2018-03-22',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
};
const res = fetch('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges', opts).then(
    (res) => res.json()
);
```

this is my current post request but it is showing me error , i believe it is format issue , but can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the error message you got before asking for help, either way after looking at your code i found some issues.

at this part

```js
const res = fetch('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges', opts).then(
    (res) => res.json()
);
```

you cannot assign the result of `fetch` to a constant becuause you're using `.then` to handle the promise and the returning value is passed to the callback, second `res.json()` returns a promise as well, and you're not handling it.

This would solve the above stated problems

```js
const res = await fetch('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges', opts);
const jsonRes = await res.json();
// using async await
```

if you don't wanna use async/await

```js
fetch('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges', opts)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(jsonRes => console.log(jsonRes));
```